# Error: object not found after being defined in R

Tags: r, csv

I have just started using R, and I seem to be falling over at the first hurdle...

I have defined an object in my R project which is the csv data for a file I have stored on my PC:

```
rgvaAssessment<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\cheddar\\Downloads\\attachments\\rgva_assessment X.csv")
```

However, when I type the object name in the R console, I get the following error:

```
> rgvaAssessment
Error: object 'rgvaAssessment' not found
```

Could someone please let me know what obvious error I am making here? The file definitely exists in the defined location.

Thanks

Comment: Do you get an error when reading the file?

Comment: @AllanCameron do you mean outside of Rstudio or by using a read function within Rstudio? Sorry to sound so dense

Comment: I mean do you get an error after the `read.csv` line of R code?

Comment: @AllanCameron no, there doesn't appear to be any error - only when I try and call the object in the console

Comment: Can you try restarting your Rstudio session and re-running the code to make sure you are not getting an error? Also, does `file.exists("C:\\Users\\cheddar\\Downloads\\attachments\\rgva_assessment X.csv")` return `TRUE`?

Comment: After you run `read.csv`, try running `ls()` to see all the current variable names. Is it shown there? Are you reading the CSV in a function? Did you actually execute the line that reads the CSV?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue using R studio. What I was doing wrong was pressing `ctrl + Enter` to run the code.

Only `ctrl + Enter` will run the current selection.  So the only code being run was the line I selected with my cursor.

To run all of the code, you can use `ctrl + shift + A`.